# UITableViewCell height of >=2048 not allowed in iOS 10?

Tags: ios10

I am working on a project that requires fairly sizable `UITableViewCell`s (with large blocks of text in them). In iOS 9, it was not a problem if these cells exceeded a height of 2048. However, iOS 10 seems less forgiving. Whenever a cell reaches that height, the `UITableView` either renders incorrectly or glitches in some other way (e.g. no scrolling).

I have found this to be reproducible in a bare-bones project. First, create a `UIViewController` that displays a single (dynamic)  `UITableViewCell`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0
        self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ExampleCell", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = "Content"

        return cell
    }
}
```

Then, create a `UITableView` with a prototype cell containing a single `UIView` with 5 constraints: top (0), left (0), right (0), height (2048) , bottom (0) (with a lower priority on bottom). It seems I can't post images due to lacking reputation, so an image of the `UITableView` setup can be found here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFazo.png

A side-by-side of the same setup with height 2047 vs 2048 can be seen here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMx7F.jpg
The `UITableView` with a cell of height 2048 does not actually have that height; as soon as you scroll down, the `UITableView` elastic bands right back up. The 2047 (or less) version works as expected.

Is this behavior intentional on Apple's part, or is something else amiss here?

Comment: Off topic, but have you considered `UIStackView` instead? There are open-sourced alternatives available for older iOS versions that you can fall back on, and I'm sure it'd handle this without issue.

Comment: It's definitely an alternative, but for now I am just wondering why iOS 10 is dealing with this issue differently than iOS 9 and earlier. Large UITableViewCells weren't a problem before.